# Load Data Local Infile slow and crashes MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, innodb, myisam

I'm trying to import a huge csv file into my database in my Laravel Web App: 500,000 rows, 93 columns, and around 700mb file size.

According to my information the best way to handle this amount of data is to use `MyISAM` & a `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` query, however when I try to load the file my script hangs for hours. When cancelling it, it seem that the MySQL server crashes as well - can't run migrations or other inserts until I manually restart the `mysql` service.

This is my code:

```
DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec("set unique_checks = 0;");
DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec("set foreign_key_checks = 0;");
DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec("alter table task_metas disable keys;");

 $query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$path'
    INTO  TABLE task_metas
    CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '$delimiter'
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '$enclosed'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '$lineending'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (@col1,     @col2, @col3, @col4, @col5, @col6, @col7, @col8, @col9,
                @col10, @col11, @col12, @col13, @col14, @col15, @col16,
                @col17, @col18, @col19, @col20, @col21, @col22, @col23,
                @col24, @col25, @col26, @col27, @col28, @col29, @col30,
                @col31, @col32, @col33, @col34, @col35, @col36, @col37,
                @col38, @col39, @col40, @col41, @col42, @col43, @col44,
                @col45, @col46, @col47, @col48, @col49, @col50, @col51,
                @col52, @col53, @col54, @col55, @col56, @col57, @col58,
                @col59, @col60, @col61, @col62, @col63, @col64, @col65,
                @col66, @col67, @col68, @col69, @col70, @col71, @col72,
                @col73, @col74, @col75, @col76, @col77, @col78, @col79,
                @col80, @col81, @col82, @col83, @col84, @col85, @col86,
                @col87, @col88, @col89, @col90, @col91, @col92, @col93
    )
SET task_id=null,
        project_id=$project->id, full_comment=null, relevance=-1,
        note=null, url=@col1, indexed=@col2, published=@col3,
        search_indexed=@col4, title_snippet=@col5, content_snippet=@col6,
        title=@col7, content=@col8, root_url=@col9, domain_url=@col10,
        host_url=@col11, parent_url=@col12, lang=@col13, porn_level=@col14,
        fluency_level=@col15, spam_level=@col16, sentiment=@col17,
        source_type=@col18, post_type=@col19, cluster_id=@col20,
        meta_cluster_id=@col21, tags_internal=@col22, tags_marking=@col23,
        tags_customer=@col24, entity_urls=@col25, images_url=@col26,
        images_width=@col27, images_height=@col28, images_legend=@col29,
        videos_url=@col30, videos_width=@col31, videos_height=@col32,
        videos_legend=@col33, pagemonitoring_sitemon_siteid=@col34,
        matched_profile=@col35, article_extended_attributes_facebook_shares=@col36,
        article_extended_attributes_facebook_likes=@col37, article_extended_attributes_twitter_retweets=@col38,
        article_extended_attributes_url_views=@col39, article_extended_attributes_pinterest_likes=@col40,
        article_extended_attributes_pinterest_pins=@col41, article_extended_attributes_pinterest_repins=@col42,
        article_extended_attributes_youtube_views=@col43, article_extended_attributes_youtube_likes=@col44, article_extended_attributes_youtube_dislikes=@col45, article_extended_attributes_instagram_likes=@col46, article_extended_attributes_twitter_shares=@col47, article_extended_attributes_num_comments=@col48, source_extended_attributes_alexa_pageviews=@col49, source_extended_attributes_facebook_followers=@col50, source_extended_attributes_twitter_followers=@col51, source_extended_attributes_instagram_followers=@col52, source_extended_attributes_pinterest_followers=@col53, extra_article_attributes_world_data_continent=@col54, extra_article_attributes_world_data_country=@col55, extra_article_attributes_world_data_country_code=@col56, extra_article_attributes_world_data_region=@col57, extra_article_attributes_world_data_city=@col58, extra_article_attributes_world_data_longitude=@col59, extra_article_attributes_world_data_latitude=@col60, extra_author_attributes_id=@col61, extra_author_attributes_type=@col62, extra_author_attributes_name=@col63, extra_author_attributes_birthdate_date=@col64, extra_author_attributes_birthdate_resolution=@col65, extra_author_attributes_gender=@col66, extra_author_attributes_image_url=@col67, extra_author_attributes_short_name=@col68, extra_author_attributes_url=@col69, extra_author_attributes_world_data_continent=@col70, extra_author_attributes_world_data_country=@col71, extra_author_attributes_world_data_country_code=@col72, extra_author_attributes_world_data_region=@col73, extra_author_attributes_world_data_city=@col74, extra_author_attributes_world_data_longitude=@col75,
        extra_author_attributes_world_data_latitude=@col76, extra_source_attributes_world_data_continent=@col77, extra_source_attributes_world_data_country=@col78, extra_source_attributes_world_data_country_code=@col79, extra_source_attributes_world_data_region=@col80, extra_source_attributes_world_data_city=@col81, extra_source_attributes_world_data_longitude=@col82, extra_source_attributes_world_data_latitude=@col83, engagement=@col84, reach=@col85, provider=@col86, generator_type=@col87, source_extended_attributes_alexa_unique_visitors=@col88, article_extended_attributes_twitter_likes=@col89, extra_author_attributes_description=@col90, article_extended_attributes_linkedin_shares=@col91,
        extra_source_attributes_name=@col92, word_count=@col93,
        created_at=NOW(), updated_at=NOW()";

    $results = DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec($query);

    DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec("set unique_checks = 1;");
    DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec("set foreign_key_checks = 1;");
    DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec("alter table task_metas enable keys;");
```

My source file isn't very easy to deal with either - it's column names do not match my table column names, and there are also some additional columns in my database that I manually set in the query.

I also tried with InnoDB by removing the alter table queries and enclosing the load data query in

```
DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec("set autocommit = 0;");
// query as above
DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec("commit;");
```

and I also set the `innodb-autoinc-lock-mode` variable in my `mysql.conf` file to a value of `2` but i resulted in the same behaviour as with myisam.

I don't know if it's normal, but during the query I don't see anything happening in the database, no new rows are inserted. Is that normal?

I also tried with a smaller file that *only* has 170,000 rows - again, same results.

My server configuration is a DigitalOcean droplet with 2 CPUs and 2GBs of RAM running Ubuntu 16.05 and the application is deployed with [Laravel Forge](https://forge.laravel.com/). The web server is an Nginx 11.x

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem wasn't with the server at all - I simply set the wrong delimiter & line ending character!

I created my test data on Excel 2016 Mac and turns out it sets the delimiter to a semicolon and the new line character to `\r` by default. I simply changed those variables and now imports everything in 20 seconds.